# Angular routing, apache rewrite, browser caching

Tags: angularjs, apache

Using the angular ngroute to route the app to any desired html file, but just don't understand why it does not work when i refreshed the page by clicking on the refresh button or `F5`, it gave an error of page 404. Have been playing .htaccess file, but does not help much.  I have to go back to the base directory and click the menu again.

If i am on the page `http://localhost/test/master/material` and trying to refresh the page by hitting the `f5` it will show page 404.

Another things is why the browser keep the cache of the page, sometime it does not reflect to changes that i have made in the html file, it just still show the old page, i have manually clear the cache before it show the new html.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'controllers', 'ngAnimate']) 
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider   
    .when('/master/material', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/master/material.html',
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

**index.html**

```
  <base href="http://localhost/test/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer.

Hope this can help others.

change the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

change base tag in head

```
<base href="/test/">
```

Comment: Note that the RewriteCond does not work with VirtualHost which requires to prepend the document root like so: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`- took me a while to figure that out, so I hope it helps someone else, too.